# Twitter bot with node.js filter retweets

Tags: node.js, twitter, bots

I’m making a basic Twitter bot that will search Tweets for a certain word and reply to them.

The problem is that it replies to both Tweets and Retweets, but I want it to reply to Tweets only. How can I filter the Retweets from the stream?

I tried `{ track: 'hello -filter:retweets'}` and it didn’t work.

```js
console.log('The bot is starting');


var ntwitter = require('ntwitter');

var bot = new ntwitter({
  consumer_key: '---',
  consumer_secret: '---',
  access_token_key:  '---',
  access_token_secret: '---'
});

var callback = function handleError(error) {
   if (error) {
   console.error('response status:', error.statusCode);
   console.error('data:', error.data);
  }
};

function startStreaming() {

  bot.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'hello'}, function(stream) {

    console.log('Listening for Tweets...');

    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {

      if (tweet.text.match(/hello/)) {

          bot.updateStatus('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + 'hello' , {in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id_str} , callback);
          console.log("done")
       }
      });

     });
}


startStreaming();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `retweeted_status`

```
stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
    if (!tweet.retweeted_status) {
    //...
```

I also wrote a tiny twitter like bot, maybe it helps you: 
https://github.com/abimelex/twivorite